# Magento2: Resolution image

Tags: magento2, image-resizing

We have too hight resolution images: https://prnt.sc/rsfqy4

and product photos are loading quite slowly. Is there any way to display reduced image quality on the frontend on products list?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom theme first if you haven't created yet.
`https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html`

If you already created a custom theme then you need to copy view.xml from `/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/etc/view.xml` and paste in your theme folder like `Vendor/Theme/etc/view.xml`

now you can customize the resolution of product images for every page where the product images showing, below code is for product listing grid view

```
<image id="category_page_grid" type="small_image">
   <width>240</width>
   <height>300</height>
</image>
```

and for list view

```
<image id="category_page_list" type="small_image">
   <width>240</width>
   <height>300</height>
</image>
```

you can change the width height of product images according to your uploaded images dimension.

**Note:** The id attribute of image tag showing specific image view identifier which is self explanatory.